# Android Room Inheritance Strategy Single Table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I am about to use Android Room library in my application.

Since i have a few subclasses which extend a base type, i was wondering whether
it would be a good approach to have a Single Table of this type in my database.

Is that possible in Android Room?

This strategy is provided in Java's ORM tool (Hibernate/JPA) , but i haven't found anything for Android Room.

Comment: "Is that possible in Android Room?" -- yes. [This project directory](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.4/MiscSamples/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/misc/polysingle) contains two models (`Comment` and `Link`) that extend a single Room entity (`NoteEntity`) and are stored in a single database table.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. Could you please explain me the concept on that? As far as i see, you don't use annotation in your subclasses? And as a result, the provider uses only the annotation provided in the super classes and creates the corresponding columns found in each subclass?

Comment: The columns are all in the superclass. Basically, the superclass contains the superset of the columns across the subclasses. In [my book that uses this example](https://commonsware.com/Room), I compare and contrast this approach with [this sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.4/MiscSamples/src/main/java/com/commonsware/room/misc/poly), using the same classes but where each subclass gets its own table.

Comment: Ok, i see. The difference between those two samples is that in the 'poly' sample, the Comment entity class is annotated with 'Entity'. 

Thanks a lot!